# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'match'

Tags: python

**code:**

```
import pandas as pd

input = pd.read_csv("resale-flat-prices.csv", header=None)

ans = []

for row in input:
    if(input.iloc[row,2].match("3 ROOM") and input.iloc[row,7].match("ADJOINED FLAT")):
        ans.append(input[row])

print(ans)
```

to find rows of data from a csv file with the following matches and append it to a new list, how should i check and match the string terms?

**update:**

i have edited using the "in" operator as follows:

if("3 ROOM" in input.iloc[row,2] and "ADJOINED FLAT" in input.iloc[row,7]):

the result produced is an empty list, does the issue lie with the reading of the csv file?

first 3 rows of data from csv file:

1990-01| ANG MO KIO|    1 ROOM| 309|    ANG MO KIO AVE 1|   04 TO 06|   31| IMPROVED|   1977|   6000
1990-01|    ANG MO KIO| 1 ROOM| 309|    ANG MO KIO AVE 1|   07 TO 09|   31| IMPROVED|   1977|   6000
1990-01|    ANG MO KIO| 1 ROOM| 309|    ANG MO KIO AVE 1|   10 TO 12|   31| IMPROVED| 1977| 8000

there are 10 columns in total

Answer (score 4):

To check for string equality, just use the `==` operator:

```
>>> my_string = "3 ROOM"
>>> my_string == "3 ROOM"
True
>>> my_string == "3 ROOMS"
False
```

To check if a string contains a substring, use the `in` operator:

```
>>> my_string = "13 ROOMS"
>>> "3 ROOM" in my_string
True
>>> "30 ROOM" in my_string
False
```

To do a more advanced string comparison, you might want to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string = "3 ROOM"
>>> re.match(r"^\d ROOM$", my_string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f4ac226bb90>
>>> re.match(r"^\d ROOMS$", my_string)
None
```

Comment: i have edited using the "in" operator as follows:   if("3 ROOM" in input.iloc[row,2] and "ADJOINED FLAT" in input.iloc[row,7]): ans.append(input[row])   the result produced is an empty list, does the issue lie with the reading of the csv file?   first 3 rows of data from csv file:   1990-01 ANG MO KIO 1 ROOM 309 ANG MO KIO AVE 1 04 TO 06 31 IMPROVED 1977 6000   1990-01 ANG MO KIO 1 ROOM 309 ANG MO KIO AVE 1 07 TO 09 31 IMPROVED 1977 6000   1990-01 ANG MO KIO 1 ROOM 309 ANG MO KIO AVE 1 10 TO 12 31 IMPROVED 1977 8000  

there are 10 columns in total

Comment: @vixk update your question with this new information, your comment is not readable enough for me to help you

Comment: Looks like your CSV file does not use commas between the fields? If so, you want to specify the delimiter to the read_csv function. For example, if the fields are separated by the pipe character (|), then you want to use pd.read_csv("resale-flat-prices.csv", header=None, delimiter="|")

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the Regexp, You can use operator `in`

```
 for row in input:
     if("3 ROOM" in input.iloc[row,2] and "ADJOINED FLAT" in input.iloc[row,7]):
         ans.append(input[row])
```

Comment: Be careful with "IN", as you might get unexpected matches, such as "13 ROOMS", "3 ROOMMATES" or "3 ROOMS WERE NUKED".  ;-)